# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')

Tags: typeerror

```
  burger.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
rightNav.classlist.toggle('v-class-resp');
navbar.classlist.toggle('h-nav-resp');
navList.classlist.toggle('v-class-resp');
```

})

This 'navbar' is showing error.

Comment: Can you check is `navbar` exist or being assigned to anything? That's what the error said `navbar` is undefined means.

Answer (score 0):

You should use class**L**ist, not class**l**ist